# Trying to add to React State Array using spread or push, Error: TypeError: array is not iterable

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, push

I've created an array in the initial state object and I'm trying to add items to the array whenever a checkbox is checked and remove the item whenever it's unchecked.

The function I'm using is pretty simple and I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work. I'm using setState to spread the items in the array and add the new item on the end, but I keep getting a TypeError on the browser saying that the array is not iterable. I've tried using `typeof` to see if it's an array and it results in `undefined`.

[Click here to see the error I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88q2h.png)

My code is:

```
class Step3 extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            missingList: [],
        }

    }

    handleChangeArray = e => {
        this.setState({
            missingList: [...this.state.missingList, e.target.name]
        })
        console.log(this.state.missingList)
    }

    render() {

        const { currentProductType, ProductSubtype } = this.props

        return (
            <div className="row mt-4">

                <h4 className='subtitle'>Missing List</h4>

                {
                    systemData[`${currentProductType}`][`${ProductSubtype}`].parts.map((item, _id) =>
                        <CustomCheckbox
                            col={3}
                            key={_id}
                            name={item}
                            text={item}
                            onChange={this.handleChangeArray}
                        />
                    )

                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The systemData points to a nested object where the list comes from and uses the `map` method to render the checkbox

Comment: Been a while since I've used class-based but i believe you either need to use an updater function or provide a completely new array. You can also use concat:  ```this.setState({missingList: this.state.missingList.concat( e.target.name)})``` since that returns a new array.

Comment: can you try to log the `this.state.missingList`, before `setState`

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I just tried it and it came up as ```undefined```

Comment: @DannyMoshe I get a different error when I use one of the array methods: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'concat')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is because the `handleChange` is not bound to the `Step3` class.
So, when `CustomCheckBox` invokes the `handleChange`, the context of `this` would be referring to `CustomCheckBox` and not `Step3`. So, `this.missingList` is correctly `undefined`. It's simply the scope of `this`.

Check this minimal reproducer of your use case. Commenting the `bind` line will result in the error you have posted.
https://codesandbox.io/embed/upbeat-smoke-q0iei?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Further reading: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm sure it's right but it still won't work. I've added ```this.handleChangeArray = this.handleChangeArray.bind(this)```, passed in ```props``` to ```constructor``` & ```super```. And then I added ```onChange={() => this.props.handleChangeArray(this.props.text)}``` to my checkbox component and ```handleChangeArray={this.handleChangeArray}``` to the props. But it's still coming back with the same error. It's still saying ```not utterable```

Comment: I solved it. I forgot to mention that I have a componentDidMount function where the state is filled from local storage and since that particular variable is undefined, it set that state variable as undefined making it not iterable